How can I change the default rotation of my rigged 3d character without breaking the animations?
How can I change the default rotation(pivot point) of my rigged 3d character without breaking the animations? Any advice?
I got a rig character with a lot of animations but, every time I place it in the game engine I'm working with, it's backwards and it's causing problems where coding is concerned. I don't know how to fix it in the game engine and I really don't want to make the character again from scratch just to fix this one problem.

In every rig structure there is generally a Root bone: a bone that is directly or indirectly parent of all others bones. As you identify it, you can go to edit mode, press shift A to add a new bone (I call it "extra root") and make it parent of the Root bone).
Then in pose mode you can use this new extra root to relocate, reorient and rescale the rig as a whole, without breaking any previous animation.
If you set a keyframe on the Extra root at the start of every animation, it will take effect automatically.

